# subdifferential of fused lasso

Tags: calculus, optimization, matrix-calculus, subgradient

consider the fused lasso
$$\phi(x) = \gamma \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} |x_i - x_{i+1}|, $$

we want to find the subdifferential of $\phi$.

I tried discussing different cases for $x_i$, for example,

$$\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{x_i} 
  = \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if }  x_{i-1} < x_i < x_{i+1} \text{ or } x_{i+1} < x_i < x_{i-1} \\
   2\gamma & \text{if } x_i > \max\{ x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}\}\\
   -2\gamma & \text{if } x_i < \min\{ x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}\}\\
   [0, 2\gamma] & \text{if } x_{i-1} = x_{i} > x_{i+1}\\
   [-2\gamma, 0] & \text{if } x_{i-1} = x_{i} < x_{i+1}\\
   [-2\gamma, 2\gamma] & \text{if } x_{i-1} = x_{i} = x_{i+1}\\
    \end{cases}, \forall i \in \{2, 3, \cdots, n-1\}$$
I am not sure if it is correct and wondering if there is any simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix, $U$ be the similarly sized superdiagonal [shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix), and $e$ be the $n^{th}$ column of $I.\;$

Then construct the following vector
$$\eqalign{
Mx &= (I-ee^T-U)\,x \\
&= \Big[\,(x_1-x_2)\quad(x_2-x_3)\;\ldots\;(x_{n-1}-x_n)\quad(x_n-x_n)\;\Big]^T \\
}$$
and the associated element-wise sign vector
$$s={\rm sign}(Mx)$$
Write the objective function in terms of these new variables and calculate its (sub)gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \gamma\; s^TMx \\
d\phi &= \gamma\; s^TM\,dx &= \gamma\; (M^Ts)^Tdx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= \gamma\;(M^Ts) \\
}$$
As an example, for $n=5,\;$ the $M$ matrix looks like this
$$\eqalign{
M &= \left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1&  -1&   0&   0&   0 \\
 0&   1&  -1&   0&   0 \\
 0&   0&   1&  -1&   0 \\
 0&   0&   0&   1&  -1 \\
 0&   0&   0&   0&   0\end{array}
\right]
}$$
Not sure that this is any simpler, but it is more compact.

All the untidiness hides inside the sign function
$$
{\rm sign}(z) = \begin{cases}
\;\;{\tt+1} \quad&{\rm if}\quad z>0 \\
\big[{\tt-1},{\tt+1}\big] \quad&{\rm if}\quad z=0 \\
\;\,{\tt-1} \quad&{\rm if}\quad z<0 \\
\end{cases}
$$