# Finding subdifferentials of lasso regularizers

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a regularizer combining lasso , group lasso, and fused lasso that is given by:

$\phi\left ( x \right ) = \lambda\left \| x \right \|_{1} + \mu\sum_{i=1}^{K}\left \| x_{G_{i}} \right \| + \gamma\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\left | x_{j} - x_{j+1} \right |$

for some $\lambda,\mu,\gamma > 0$ where $G_{i} \subset \left \{ 1,2,...,n \right \}$ and $x_{G_{i}}$ is a subvector of $x$ indexed by $G_{i}$ for $i = 1,...,K$

I need to find the subdifferential $\partial \phi(x)$. For the first term, I know that the subdifferential $\partial (\lambda \|x\|_1)$ is the set of vectors $v$ such that $v_i \in \begin{cases} \{\lambda\} & x_i > 0 \\ \{-\lambda\} & x_i < 0 \\ [-\lambda, \lambda] & x_i = 0 \end{cases}$ but not sure on how to handle the rest of the terms. Any help would be much appreciated!I found this post [subdifferential of fused lasso](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871635/subdifferential-of-fused-lasso) but not sure if that's correct